# Association Rules with Orange3 using table of orders/bills - How to convert into: cloumns is Items_name, Row is OrderID for associate?

Tags: dataframe, associations, data-mining, model-associations, orange

I have a table of orders where we have many of orders, each order is an item. And in excel, you have 2 columns: OrderID and ItemName. So if u have 4 items in one order, you will have 4 row have the same orderId but different ItemName, look like this:

[image: Sample]

[image: Data origanal]

When I'm using this data for Associate-rule in Orange3, to find which Item you will buy when you buy this/these item. For sample: you buy beard, there are high chance you will buy milk or egg. Or when you buy a cake and a Coke, you have high chance to buy cups and dishes. But when I done it, in the end, there are no rule be found.I found two ways for Orange3 read the right data is

1. Same as the sample data 'FoodMart 2000', where each row is a list items in one orderID. I tried to convert the origanal data to list by using 'duplicate merge' in Excel, like this:
   [image: Duplicate_data]

[image: sample3]
But still not right, there is no rules out put. Am I missing something?

2. I find somewhere that you have to convert data into Boolean value - different table like a columsns is ID, the rest columns is Items, and the value is: 1 -have, 0 - Don't have. like this:

[image: sample2]

How do I convert the origanal data to be like above?
how do we convert the excel data into the data that Orange can read and find rules?
And I want do it by using tools/function available in Orange3 or Excel, minimun realate code.

EDIT1: After I add Quanity, underscore before merge. Input data as Excel(.xlsx)
Data table in Orange read as this:
[image: TableType]
[image: DataTable]

After this, I remove BillNo column (like FoodMarket200)
[image: editTable]

And Linked to Associate rules:
[image: Model]
[image: FrequentItems]
[image: Associaterules]
As you can see, Frequent Item read seperated item.

Comment: Supposedly, if you replace whitespaces with underscores and append `=1` to `Itemname` values before merging, Orange will recognize the file as a [basket file](https://orangedatamining.com/blog/2016/04/25/association-rules-in-orange/).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you point for what I'm missing next? I add Quanity of item, replace space with inderscores and then merge items that have same Billno, but Associate still can't read rule. Associate read each row as different items. (I edited test)